# how to write a cpp program for replace string

Tags: c++

how to write a cpp program for replace string using only 1 text file

for example if in text file abc.txt

```
Hello 
how are you 
good
bye
```

i want output like

```
Hello 
how are you 
bad
bye
```

all above thing will be done in text file

Comment: If you want to write a C++ program, why did you add the Java tag? And read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Open IDE, write code, DONE.
You're welcome

Comment: If you are asking a question, you are asking other people to devote your time to your cause. If you want that, make sure that **you** yourself devoted time to it. If you don't even write in whole sentences, this is doubtable. If you want the code of a whole program after you only stated what looks like homework, this is highly doubtable. What you ask here is something like "To achieve ... I tried this code ... but it does not work because ...". The right response to your question would thus be the link to a basic c++ tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty easy. Open the file, get the text.  Then iterate throw each word and ask the user if he/she wants to change that word. If yes, write new word on new file. If not, write old word on new file.

Now you just need to translate that to c++

Comment: i don't want to create any new file i want to write in same file can you give me code